# How to automatically translate some node of XML file?

Tags: xml, bash, translation, google-translate, xmlstarlet

I need to translate the `<DefaultValue>` tag in a file similar to this (~45k lines) :

```
<Resources>
  <Resource>
    <File>App_GlobalResources\Ecommerce_Modules.ascx.resx</File>
    <Key>ModuleTitle.ecTermsAndConds</Key>
    <DefaultValue>Terms And Conditions</DefaultValue>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Resource>
  <Resource>
    <File>App_GlobalResources\Ecommerce_Modules.ascx.resx</File>
    <Key>ModuleTitle.ecStorefrontCatalogMenu</Key>
    <DefaultValue>Catalog Menu</DefaultValue>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </Resource>
...
</Resources>
```

I looked at Google Translator Toolkit, but it doesn't support arbitrary XML. There is some paid services, but for now a Google Translate would be enough.

I can extract all the  tag/text with `xmlstarlet` but how can I update the value with the translation ?

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/Resources/Resource" -c "./DefaultValue" -n ~/Downloads/Resources.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create my [own Bash script](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/xml-translator) to solve this problem using `curl`, [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) and `google web translator`.

### Principle

I'm looping on each element containing text to translate, calling a translating function (e.g. Google Translate), and updating the given element in the output file with the translation.
So you need to define the XPath for your expression inside the script file :

```
# @description Xpath to each item is build as $xpath[i]/$i18nTag
xpath="/Resources/Resource"
i18nTag="DefaultValue"
```

Then run :

```
./xml-translator.bash en fr ./input.xml
```

Check result in `./input.fr.xml`.

### Disclaimer

- The project is not an out-of-the-box solution –due to Google Terms of Services– but should give a good start on this issue.

### Repository

Check it on [github: **XML-translator**](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/xml-translator).